# Maintain cookie session with jersey CLIENT per client

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using the **client** part of jersey API.

I am querying a rest endpoint that send me back a cookie like this one

```
Set-Cookie: SessionId=270080680;path=/myPath
```

Reading the doc and other Stack Overflow answers I am able to retrieve the cookie and send it back.

But can Jersey manage this cookie handling automatically per client? And send back what is needed to be sent back according to the path for example.

As suggested in comment the right way seems to create a filter and intercept request to store and reemit the cookie.

This solve one part of the problem, I still need to be clever and check the path of the endpoint to know which cookie I should send.

Can jersey do it for me?

Comment: I would use a ClientRequestFilter in combination with ClientResponseFilter. You can get the cookies from the response filter and store them and send them out in the request filter.

Comment: this is where I am going to go, but this solve one part of the problem. I still need to be clever and in my simple example I still need to check that the request endpoint has /mypath as an ancestor... Can jersey do it for me ?

Comment: Yes, play around with the ClientRequestContext of ClientRequestFilter. Get the UriInfo. You will find URI related methods you can use to check.

Comment: ok i will do that no problem. But it means that I ll need to reinvent the wheel if i want to be correct...

Comment: You're not reinventing anything because no such thing exists. I think the RESTEasy client had some browser cookies implementation but it is not compatible with Jersey client. And  I think it might have been deprecated. But if the source code is still there, you can get some ideas for implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not applicable for everyone but in my case this solution fit perfectly ! So I decided to share it

As suggested I started to create my own filter and everything seems ok! But sometimes I have seen that my cookie were duplicated.

After digging this is what i found, so I am in the particular context of a JavaFX application and using the simplest jersey client implementation relying on HttpURLConnection.

I notice that my cookie were duplicated from the time that my app display a WebView.
I found this piece of code in WebPage.java

```
    if (CookieHandler.getDefault() == null) {
        boolean setDefault = Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty(
                "com.sun.webkit.setDefaultCookieHandler",
                "true"));
        if (setDefault) {
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
        }
    }
```

So the bug was in fact my answer. Someone already take care of managing cookie in my case

The one line managing all cookie jvm wide is :

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

I let you check the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) to understand how to use it